# C#: Null reference exception thrown while using XmlDocment

Tags: c#, xml, nullreferenceexception

A `NullReferenceException` is thrown by the runtime when I convert XElement into XmlNode using the following function:

```
public static XmlNode GetXmlNode(this XElement element)
{
    using (XmlReader xmlReader = element.CreateReader())
    {
        XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
        xmlDoc.Load(xmlReader);
        xmlDoc.ChildNodes[4].InnerXml = "0.15"; ====> null reference exception occurs here
        return xmlDoc;
    }
}
```

How can I convert XElement to XmlNode without this problem?

Comment: Does ChildNodes (an XmlNodeList) throw an index out of range exception or return null when you try to access a node that does not exist? Are you sure the node you are trying to change exists?

Comment: it exists it doesit throw exception

Comment: i like to convertXelement into xmlnode

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Access the `DocumentElement` first in order to get the root:

```
xmlDoc.DocumentElement.ChildNodes[4].InnerXml = "0.15";
```

**EDIT:** an `XmlDocument` inherits from `XmlNode`. You should be able to simply do this:

```
XmlNode node = xmlDoc.DocumentElement;
return node;
```

If you need to cast it for a particular method you could use `(XmlNode)xmlDoc.DocumentElement` or `xmlDoc.DocumentElement as XmlNode`.

Comment: how can i convert it into XMLNode